# Add link to parent item of multi-level Bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I'm following this tutorial on how to make a vertical multi-level Bootstrap menu. And so far, everything works. Except for one thing, the parent items are clickable, but the only thing they do is that they collapse the menu. I need to be able to give them an href such as "/en/boardgames".

The code from the tutorial I've followed:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <!-- column1, Vertical Dropdown Menu -->
            <div id="main-menu" class="list-group">
                <a href="#sub-menu" class="list-group-item active" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#main-menu">Item 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div class="collapse list-group-level1" id="sub-menu">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 2</a>
                    <a href="#sub-sub-menu" class="list-group-item" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-menu">Sub Item 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <div class="collapse list-group-level2" id="sub-sub-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 1</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 2</a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-parent="#sub-sub-menu">Sub Sub Item 3</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 2</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 3</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 4</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Item 5</a>
            </div>    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <!-- column 2, content goes here... -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the parent items contains href="#sub-menu", this is needed to make the menu collapse.

What I want is, that the menu collapses and that it also links to a page like "/en/boardgames".

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: What is the meaning of collapsing the menu when you are going to another page? When the new page loads the menu structure will be as predesiged.

Comment: It's for a webshop, the parent item is the main category, and the child items the sub categories. When clicking the parent (main category), all items of that category need to be displayed.

Comment: So what do you want on click on the parent item, redirect to another page or collapse the content ?

Comment: @pbenard load webshop items (a page) on the right of the menu and collapsing the menu as well